# Using Google API to connect other people to my Google Calander - Using JavaScript.

Tags: javascript, api

I need a little bit of help.
I manage to use the Oauth2.0 and the gapi.auth.authorize to authorize from a web application and synchronize my calander and my events
but I want other people to connect my calander from the web application but without showing them my username & password - **so they can scheduale
new events on my calander.** 
how can I do it using javascript????

thank you in advance...